# Minimum standard random generator basics

Tags: algorithm, random

Minimum standard random number generator.

I am reading about minimum standard number generator as below

> Given a random integer xn, the next random integer in a random
>   sequence is given by computing xn+1 = a xn (mod m), where a = 7 ^ 5 =
>   16807 and m = 2^31 − 1 = 2147483647; as a check on your
>   implementation, if x0 = 1, then x10000 = 1043618065.
>
> Park and Miller chose m as the largest Mersenne prime less than 2^32;
>   the smallest primitive root of m is 7, and since 5 is also prime, 7^5
>   is also a primitive root, hence their choice of a. Because a is a
>   primitive root of m, all values in the range 1 to m − 1 inclusive will
>   be generated before any repeat, so the random number generator has full
>   period. The multiplier a = 16807 has been shown to have good
>   randomness properties.
>
> Subsequent to their original paper, Park and Miller recommended 48271
>   as an improvement, and some people use 69621, but we’ll continue to
>   use 16807. The easiest way to implement that is obvious: just
>   multiply a by the current value of x and compute the modulus.
>
> But that may cause overflow in the intermediate multiplication,
>   rendering the results incorrect.
>
> A trick of Linus Schrage allows that multiplication to be done without
>   overflow: Compute q = ⌊m / a⌋ and r = m (mod a) so that m = a q + r.
>   Then
>
> a new x can be computed by hi = ⌊x / q⌋, lo = x (mod q), x = a · lo −
>   r · hi, then adding m to x if x ≤ 0.

My question is how author has computed new x in terms of as hi = floor(x/q) and lo = x(modq). I am looking for steps here. Kindly expain.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics more than programming

Comment: The issue about avoiding overflow is clearly about programming, not about mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify the notation. Set H = hi and L = lo. We have m = a * q + r. A simple calculation shows that q = 127773 and r = 2836. We observe that a < q.

Now let x_{n} be given and calculate H = x_{n} / q and L = x_{n} % q. So, x_{n} = q * H + L with L < q.

By definition x_{n+1} = a * x_{n} mod m. Calculating the right-hand-side (before reduction mod m) we get a * x_{n} = a * (q * H + L) = a * q * H + a * L = (m - r) * H + a * L = m * H - r * H + a * L.

Now let's consider r * H. Clearly 0 <= r * H < a * (x_{n} / q). As x_{n} < m and as observed above a < q, a * (x_{n} / q) < m. In particular, it doesn't overflow.

Likewise 0 < a * L < a * q < m. So, again no overflow.

We conclude that x_{n+1} = m * H - r * H + a * L. Reducing the latter modulo m we get x_{n+1} = -r * H + a * L with neither of the two right-hand-side expressions overflowing m. If the sum is negative we add m and we are done.

Comment: I am trying to related above explanation above can you eloborate Reducing the latter modulo m we get x_{n+1} = -r * H + a * L . How can you conclude that?

Comment: @ thanks for explanation. how we got Clearly 0 <= r * H < a * (x_{n} / q). ? Request to explain.

Comment: @venkysmarty r = m mod a. Hence r < a. Indeed from the first paragraph we know that r = 2836 while a = 16807. H = x_{n} / q by definition. Hence r * H <= a * (x_{n} / q). Yes, they can be equal in case H = 0. The argument still holds.